# Static HTML or generate Dynamic HTML | performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, optimization

I want to know which method is faster/better and why.

I have a Web App. It has lot of HTML Tags like:

```html
<div id="info-view">
  <h3 class="h3-title">Info</h3>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Version</h4>
    <div class="version">
      <p class="list-item">APP Version: <span id="app-vr"></span>
      ...so on
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="import-view">
  <h3 class="h3-title">Import</h3>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Import List</h4>
    <div id="import-container">
      <div class="import-data">
        <p class="import-name">Data bla blabla</p>
      </div>
      <div class="import-data">
        ...
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- And lot of other View container like these...online-view...setting-view... -->
```

And everytime I need a view to be shown, I put the style.display from the current one to 'none' and the view I need to 'block'.

Now my question is:
Would it be better to generate the div-blocks in javascript? 
Like:

```js
    // remove the current content from the DOM
    while(document.body.firstChild) {
      document.body.firstChild.remove();
    }
    // generate the new content
    var infoView = document.createElement("div");
    infoView.id = "info-view";

    var title = document.createElement("h3");
    title.classList.add("he-title");
    title.textContent = "Info";
    ...
    // add it to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(infoView);
```

If I need another view I will just remove the current one completly from the DOM and generate the new one and display it.

Which one is better for performance/readability/code maintenance ?

Because in my code I do a lot with the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use https://jsperf.com to check your DOM manipulation performance.

For your case performace measurement shows that adding/removing elements are faster operation than showing/hiding in Chrome.

You can rerun this test in different browsers to measure operation and create different flows based on browser type to always use better alternative.

[image]
https://jsperf.com/show-hide-or-add-removes